# Отношение гуглов к генераторам контента

Tags: seo, content

Есть сайт, специализирующийся на продаже деталей. Для него нужно добавить из базы около 4к товаров. Пишу для него бота, который используя переменные будет создавать самогенерирующийся текст. Помимо переменных есть ветки синонимов ("Перед Вами", "Представляем Вам" и т.д.).
Как вы думаете, не пессимизируют ли меня за таких выходки, и ещё, есть ли у гуглов порог добавления контента (возможно это будет тревожным звоночком для поисковика, если за сутки на сайт добавится овер 1к товаров)

Comment: Неоригинальный, бесполезный контент. Санкции.

Answer (score 2):

Цитата из **[Рекомендаций Гугл для вебмастеров](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=ru)**:

> "Не используйте следующие методы:
>
> **[Автоматически сгенерированное
>   содержание](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306)** (*Автоматически сгенерированным называется
>   содержание, созданное с помощью программных средств*)".

Ваша идея противоречит правилам Гугл.